# Custom regexp for rails validates_format_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application that has table attributes with special requirements. In the form they need to provide me a very special kind of date format.
the format in question is:

Year.month.day

I prefer to use the validates :format helper of Rails to make it a little cleaner, but i'm not very good with regular expressions. Any idea that enlights me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 validates :date, :format => { :with => /^[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}$/, :message => "Invalid Date" }
```

Not the best practice. Also all this forget about bissext year and month's number of days

Comment: Thanks so much for the regexp, nailed it. it even controls the number of digits between spaces. About bissext and number of days i don't want to look into it, the date format is enough mess to deal with. Again, thanks so much! You made my day!

Comment: We are here for that! I'm glad that I could help you!

Answer (score -1):

You can try http://rubular.com/ to test your regex.